# Dealing with different scores from Solr replicas

Tags: solr, solrcloud, tf-idf

In Solr's default scoring implementation, deleted documents are still considered when calculating scores. The number of deleted documents on replicas of a shard are not guaranteed to be the same, and hence the different replicas may give slightly different scores.

We are currently using a setup with 8 shards each having 2 replicas. For paging search results it is vital that the sort order is deterministic to avoid missing documents/skipping documents when paging.

Possible ways of dealing with this that come to mind are to use a different scoring algorithm or to try to require tools using the system to send queries to the same replicas that served their first query (this would obviously go badly wrong if that replica was later down!). As the issue is different scoring between replicas, rather than different scoring between shards, I don't think Solr's distributed IDF settings help.

Comment: How large is the difference in the number of deleted documents? I'm not sure how you'd end up with a widely different number of deleted documents as long as your servers are configured with the same mergefactors, etc.

Comment: The difference in number is not that large e.g. for one shard the two replicas report 59,163 vs 58,973 deleted documents. Each replica in this case has Num Docs: 2,028,166, and the scores between the replicas are close (deviation at the 3rd decimal place)... but it's not uncommon for documents to have very similar scores. In these cases the absolute ordering of the results doesn't matter, just that the ordering is deterministic.